# Caliburn Micro & Valueconvertor

Tags: caliburn.micro

When using `Caliburn.Micro` short hand syntax for events, how do we pass a `Enum` (via ValueConvertor) ?

```
<MenuItem Header="Open" cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click]=[Action ShowDesigner(<what goes here ?>,'False')]"/>
```

Where `ShowDesigner` method sytax is

```
ShowDesigner(eReportType,bool)
```

I have already written `StringToEnumValueconvertor`.

**Update**

EnumConvertor is as follows

```
 public class StringToEnumConvertor : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return Enum.Parse(typeof(eReportingTool), (string)value);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

While the enum looks as

```
 public enum eReportingTool
{
    StimulsoftReports = 1,
    FastReport
}
```

Comment: yes it does, sorry had forgot to mark answer, will do it rightaway

Comment: Glad I could help :]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need converter to convert from string to enum, just pass your enum item as string.

```
cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click]=[Action ShowDesigner('StimulsoftReports','false')"
```